# good postgresql client for windows?

Tags: postgresql

coming back to postgresql after several years of oracle ...

what are the state-of-the art postgresql administrative/ddl generating/data inserting frontends on windows? it would be nice if it had integration for postgis as well. it should be standalone or alternatively a plugin for intellij idea

thinking back, all the windows programs specific for postgresql i have used were crap, especially PGAdmin. had it become better?

Comment: For questions like these, I think sometimes the best place to look is http://alternativeto.net

Comment: Here is a [list of software available](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools#Open_Source_.2F_Free_Software) Trying out LibreOffice right now and it seems to work well with PostgreSQL

Comment: very funny of you to close a question from '08 at the end of '12

Comment: yep pgadmin is crap, I don't know why some devs force advice to use it :(

Comment: As an alternative to pgadmin we have been writing http://sqlectron.github.io/ its open source

Comment: Really enjoying using this. *so* much better than the horribly slow, unstable PGAdmin III

Comment: [dbForge Studio for PostgreSQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/studio/) is released!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I like [Postgresql Maestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/postgresql/maestro/). I also use their version for MySql. I'm pretty statisfied with their product. Or you can use the free tool PgAdmin.

Comment: PGMaestro seems very similar to EMS's SQL Manager (which has a free version).

Comment: This not free or open source

Comment: just tried to use PGMaestro for 3 days, it's a complete disaster, it is unusable garbage, with terrible UX, how they even sell that product...

Answer (score 24):

do you mean something like [pgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/) for administration?

Comment: PGAdmin is better now than it used to be. It still leaves a lot to desire, but it is usable.

Comment: pgAdmin doesn't even have auto complete capabilities. For me at least this is essential.

Comment: pgAdmin does not sort columns in accessible way, does not utilise tabs, just breeds windows, how crude and crappy this software is!

Comment: pgAdmin is awful. Massively unstable, and crashes regularly.  Pick something else!

Comment: pgAdmin v4 is even worse: Catastrohpically slow, bad shortcut support, grotesque UI.

Comment: I made this comment back in 2008. I believe it still has its uses but I never use it myself. :)

Answer (score 10):

I heartily recommended [dbVis](http://www.dbvis.com/).  The client runs on Mac, Windows and Linux and supports a variety of database servers, including PostgreSQL.

Comment: There's also a free version of DbVisualizer.

Comment: @newenglander: yes, the free version is very good.  That's what I use.

Comment: free version is somewhat crap. ok if all you need is only basic functionality

Comment: The free version used to be better (you could have open multiple SQL files) but recent versions are now limited to one file open at a time.  But it's still solid and for a FREE tool, it's very high quality.  Of course there are more features in the pay version.

Comment: I agree, the free version of dbVis works very well. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 9):

Actually there is a freeware version of EMS's [SQL Manager](http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/manager/download) which is quite powerful

Comment: That freeware version keeps telling me that I pirated it and shutting down. "Great" software.

Comment: Free version limits you to 5 database connections. Not database server connections, 5 *database* connections.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend Navicat strongly. What I found particularly excellent are it's import functions - you can import almost any data format (Access, Excel, DBF, Lotus ...), define a mapping between the source and destination which can be saved and is repeatable (I even keep my mappings under version control).

I have tried SQLMaestro and found it buggy (particularly for data import); PGAdmin is limited.

Comment: from what I have tried, no matter paid or free, Navicat is the best, at least they have the most intuitive UI

Answer (score 4):

For anyone looking for a web-enabled client for Postgres, I'll just put the link out here to TeamPostgreSQL, a very polished AJAX web client for pg:

http://www.teampostgresql.com

Answer (score 3):

EMS's [SQL Manager](http://sqlmanager.net/products/postgresql/manager/) is much easier to use and has many more features than either phpPgAdmin or PG Admin III. However, it's windows only and you have to pay for it.

Answer (score 1):

SQLExplorer is a great Eclipse plugin or standalone interface that works with many different database systems, either with dedicated drivers or with ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

[phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/) is PostgreSQL web frontend which is quite good.