# Good Postgres graphical client for Windows

Tags: postgresql, client

The name pretty much says it all.  Right now I'm using Squirrel - it crashes frequently and suffers from memory problems  (I've tried increasing the heap size).  I don't need anything particularly fancy or full-featured - just something that won't take up 2.4 GB of RAM to store a 1.5 million line, 8 column result set.

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105788/good-postgresql-client-for-windows

Comment: dbForge Studio for PostgreSQL is available at https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/studio/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [PgAdmin](http://www.pgadmin.org/).

However - I don't think you'll find much that won't use a large amount of memory when you have a result set with 1.5 million rows...

PgAdmin has the ability to limit automatically the number of rows returned - so you can get an overview, but not sit for an hour waiting for your results to turn up. If you write a query to return that many rows though, than you are going to have problems.

(You can also look at the `limit` SQL command, to restrict how many results you get back)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll check it out.  Out of curiosity, why would a result set that size cause memory problems for the client?

Comment: Not going to necessarily cause memory problems, but if you are returning huge result sets, there is necessarily more memory required. Both in what is required for the data itself, plus any overhead for the row information + (it sounds like) memory leaks if you run this more than once...

Comment: Oh, and returning over a million rows is definitely going to take some time to run. You usually won't need to see all million+ every time you test a query :)

Comment: Note that if you have an ORDER BY in your query, the DB may be forced to compute the entire result set before sending results even if you use LIMIT.

Answer (score 2):

Try official pgAdmin.
http://www.pgadmin.org/download/windows.php

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use [phpPgAdmin](http://phppgadmin.sourceforge.net/) on the server. It’s a web app, but it’s lightweight and easy to install.

It can paginate results, so it can handle large result sets. It can’t do everything that pgAdmin can do, but for everyday use I prefer it.

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE: This is the same answer I gave this [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105788/good-postgresql-client-for-windows).*

I recommended [dbVis](http://www.dbvis.com/).  The client runs on Mac, Windows and Linux and supports a variety of database servers, including PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

[HeidiSQL](https://www.heidisql.com/) has experimental support for postgres. I find HeidiSQL much easier to use than pgAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Try [dbeaver](https://dbeaver.io/download/)
It has support for multiple databases including postgres and also available on Windows app store.