# How to remove PostgreSQL as a service?

Tags: service, postgresql-9.5

I have installed PostgreSQL 9.5 in my machine. But there is no UI for that. When I installed pgAdmin I can view the `postsql` as a service.

Can I remove this service and install as a server like other databases(sql server, my sql)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pgAdmin III developed for PostgreSQL User Interface Or use cmd its will work. [See this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105788/good-postgresql-client-for-windows)