# Connecting to an external database without postgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How client can connect production PostgreSQL database server remotely.

In client system there is no PostgreSQL installed.

Comment: by just replace local host with production db Ip address

Comment: The connection to a remote server is the same as to a "local" server: you specify the hostname (or IP address) of the server where Postgres is running

Comment: client will not have pg admin and we need to provide only select permission to him.

Comment: we are product based company ,we have production database , the client (XYZ) want to access the database to write sql and generate reports, i need to tell them how to access the production database with only select permission.

Answer (score 0):

By just replace `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` with production db `IP address`

If you want to connect it from IDE use Squirrel SQL or other Postgres DB clients to connect it.

[good postgresql client for windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105788/good-postgresql-client-for-windows)

Your DB should be publicly accessible, or create a VPN setup between, and then you can use any of the above sql-client softwares

Comment: Client will not use pg admin, how to connect in other way.

Comment: can you elaborate who is client and how they want to access it?

Comment: we are product based company ,we have production database , the client (XYZ) want to access the database to write sql and generate reports, i need to tell them how to access the production database with only select permission.